# How do I check if there is a tag in the title

Tags: php, wp-query

I have many post with multiple tags ex: `AMOS LEE, FOO FIGHTERS,TAYLOR SWIFT`

Post only have one of the tags in the title ex: `“The Man Who Wants You” – Amos Lee`

How would I scan the_title() and go through the tags and store the matching tag in a variable?

Ive tried

```
 <?php
 $id = get_the_title();
 $posttags = get_the_tags();
 if ($posttags) {
 foreach($posttags as $tag) {
     $tag = $tag->name . '<br>';
  }
 }

 if (stripos($id,$tag) !== false) {
    echo 'true<br>';
 }else{
    echo 'false';
 }
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your loop:

```
<?php
$title = get_the_title();
$posttags = get_the_tags();

if( $title && $posttags ) {
  $result = find_tag_in_title( $title, $posttags );
  var_dump( $result ); // dump result
}
?>
```

Put this in your functions.php file:

```
<?php
function find_tag_in_title( $title, $posttags ) {

  foreach( $posttags as $tag ){
    if( strpos( strtolower($title), strtolower($tag->name) ) !== false ) return $tag->name;
  }

return false;    
}
?>
```

Comment: I getting a werid output 'STRINGSTRINGSTRINGSTRINGBOOL(FALSE)' I put the function in the functions.php file.

Comment: @Tsea I've edited the function. Try it now.

Comment: That works! Thank you. The output is `STRING(6) "ATTILA"` is this because of the var_dump?

Comment: Yes. The `var_dump();` is just there so you can see the result. You can do whatever you need do do with `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

Small changes in your code:

```
//$id = get_the_title();
$title = '"The Man Who Wants You" – Amos Lee';
//$posttags = get_the_tags();
$posttags     = array('AMOS LEE', 'FOO FIGHTERS', 'TAYLOR SWIFT');
$matched_tags = array();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach ($posttags as $tag) {
        if (stripos($title, $tag) !== false) {
            array_push($matched_tags, $tag);
        }
    }
}
print_r($matched_tags);
```

OUTPUT: your matched tags

```
Array
(
    [0] => AMOS LEE
)
```